# Como colocar linhas em um gráfico e barra?

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber como insiro linhas em um gráfico de barras.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
Periodo <- c("01/2020", "03/2020", "05/2020",
            "06/2020", "08/2020", "09/2020")
Valores <- c("0,08", "3,15", "4,91", "0,72", "6,21", "8,80")

teste <- data.frame(Periodo, Valores)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(teste) + aes(x = Periodo, y = Valores) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Comment: Altere sua pergunta para: Como adicionar linhas ao gráfico e como fazer para transformar uma coluna em dados numéricos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O principal problema parece ser o vetor `Valores` ser um vetor de classe `"character"`, os números são strings, sem qualquer valor numérico. Isso pode ser visto pelo eixo dos yy, cujas anotações são equidistantes apesar dos valores não o serem. As diferenças de um valor para o outro não são constantes mas a diferença de alturas das barras é sempre a mesma.

Para ter o gráfico certo, tem de se transformar o vetor `Valores` em vetor numérico, substituindo primeiro as vírgulas por pontos.

O gráfico final mostra os dois gráficos lado a lado com o pacote `gridExtra`, de modo a se ver melhor a diferença.

```
library(ggplot2)

Periodo <- c("01/2020", "03/2020", "05/2020",
             "06/2020", "08/2020", "09/2020")
Valores <- c("0,08", "3,15", "4,91", "0,72", "6,21", "8,80")

teste <- data.frame(Periodo, Valores)

g1 <- ggplot(teste, aes(x = Periodo, y = Valores, group = 1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Gráfico original")

Valores <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", Valores))
teste <- data.frame(Periodo, Valores)

g2 <- ggplot(teste, aes(x = Periodo, y = Valores, group = 1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Gráfico depois de 'as.numeric/sub'")

gridExtra::grid.arrange(g1, g2, nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

> Gostaria de saber como insiro linhas em um gráfico de barras.

Você pode inserir linhas utilizando o geom_line():

```
ggplot(teste, aes(x = Periodo, y = Valores, group = 1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  geom_line()
```